# UL LI hover span information box not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an information box (`span`) which allows you to hover over an `a` which is in a `ul` and `li`, and a width restricted `div`, and then for it to appear. However, it does not work (note: I have not added in the hover for the `span` to appear, but can do that with ease): the box is not aligned properly; I would like it to be floating to the right of the letter which it belongs to with a 5px gap.

I tried `absolute` positioning first to no avail if that helps.

-html-

```
<div id="album-select-side-panel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#studio">S</a>
                <span class="asp-info">
                Studio Albums
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#compilation">C</a>
                <span class="asp-info">
                Compilation Albums
                </span>
            </li><li>
                <a href="#live">L</a>
                <span class="asp-info">
                Live Albums
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

-css-

```
#album-select-side-panel
    {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -60px;
    }

#album-select-side-panel ul
    {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

#album-select-side-panel ul li a
    {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #600;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    transition: 350ms background-color;
    -moz-transition: 350ms background-color;
    -webkit-transition: 350ms background-color;
    }

#album-select-side-panel ul li a:hover
    {
    background-color: #ACD;
    }

#album-select-side-panel ul li .asp-info
    {
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    border: 2px solid #EEE;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to have the span show when you hover over the a?

Comment: @SleekGeek - No, the positioning of the span like in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning, the second way is to float `A` and `LI` (depending on the rest of HTML/CSS).

## FLOAT

Both, `A` and `SPAN` are floated, their parent has `overflow: hidden` to clear the float. And then I removed width from UL (50px).

```
#album-select-side-panel {width: auto;}
#album-select-side-panel ul li {overflow: hidden;}
#album-select-side-panel ul li > * {float: left;}
#album-select-side-panel ul li > span {margin: 9px 0 0; display: none;}
#album-select-side-panel ul li:hover > span {display: block}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eLd4L2h/3/

## ABSOLUTE POSITION

And here is the solution with absolute positioning:

```
#album-select-side-panel ul li {position: relative;}
#album-select-side-panel ul li .asp-info {position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5eLd4L2h/4/

In both I've only added the styles to the bottom, your styles are the same, just add them my rows :-)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of not making the div look expanded as it is a different colour to the background of the page, and you can see it get bigger?

Comment: Sure, everything is possible :-) but i don't know what you exactly mean.

Comment: Don't worry; I've sorted it!